# how to import all attribute to numpy module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, ubuntu-18.04, jupyter-lab

I had problem when im use this command(ubuntu 18.04) :

```
mpiexec -np 1 python3 hello-Project.py
```

the code example is :

```
import openseespy.opensees as ops
import numpy as np
import time
import sys
print (sys.version)
print(np.__version__)

pid = ops.getPID()
np = ops.getNP()
#print(dir(numpy))
prove = np.array([1, 2, 3])
nodi = numpy.array([[99,0.0,0.0,0.0]]) 

print(nodi,prove)
print('Hello World Process:', pid)
if pid == 0:
    print('Total number of processes:', np)
```

And the relative autput is :

```
3.6.8 (default, Oct  7 2019, 12:59:55) 
[GCC 8.3.0]
1.17.4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello-Project.py", line 11, in <module>
    prove = np.array([1, 2, 3])
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'array'
Process 0 Terminating
```

Im using dir command to see the numpy attribute inside py script and dont charge attribute.
But in command line python shell work and i jupyterlab too.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
...
np = ops.getNP()
# any subsequent references to "np" will find the integer, not the numpy module
```

You are shadowing the `np` reference to `numpy` when assigning the result of `ops.getNP()` (which is an integer) to the name `np`.

Either remove `as np` when importing `numpy` or choose another name for the integer returned by `ops.getNP()`